# Re-use of deleted MySql keys

Tags: mysql

Everyone says don't re-use deleted MySql keys. eg. Stack Overflow question: [I want to reuse the gaps of the deleted rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449982/i-want-to-reuse-the-gaps-of-the-deleted-rows)

I have read all of the "expert" opinions but have not found a single answer that gives a valid reason why not. Everyone simply asks "why do you want to"?

Well here is a very good reason. If my users have a choice of entering URL mysite.com/person.php?id=123 or a URL mysite.com/person.php?id=123456789123, which one would they most likely prefer?

So can anyone give me a reason why re-using 123 would be a bad idea? I am actually not talking about one record. My records get added and deleted in blocks of several thousand. Updates are very rare and I am the only person who does updates.

There are also no dependencies. Nothing points to those records so there are no integrity issues with other tables.

When I want to add another block of records I will have a simple search routine that searches for the first block of unused record keys large enough to accommodate all of the records being added. Much the same way that hard disk space usage works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys are usually used as `unique` identifiers, if they are used again, they `stop` being unique, and become `shared`. This is the logic behind the idea of not to reuse keys.

So I would suggest, split the key and the id of the user, to two fields, key the key as unique, and the id make it "choose-able" via a gap-finding function.

Before you split, create this new column called user-id, and copy to it the id (which is currently your `key`) of the users.

Then make this column unique, so that you prevent accidental cases of id reuse.

And you are "home" free.

Comment: My keys are totally unique. When I delete key 27 it is totally gone. No dependencies. The only possible dependency is people who bookmark that link. But they have never been able to do that because we regularly delete and reassign blocks of records so the numbers regularly change anyway.

Comment: So if you have good `constraints` on your tables, and you prevent accidental reuse of keys without them being purged before. There is no reason to reuse. However as I said, if you want to give your users a nice `id` don't use the `id` you use as a key, call it `user-id`

Comment: We will have 1.5M userids just as we currently have 1.5M "main keys". They will both just be random numbers so we are back where we started from.

Comment: But over time, those 1.5M userid will diverge from the id, and it will also allow you to grant access to cool user ids, such as 1111 which previously was allocated to some lost-soul